# Distribution of random variables (normal and standard normal)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and that $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ where all of the random variables are independent.  Denote $s^2_Z$ as the sample variance of $Z_1 , \ldots, Z_n$.  What is the distribution of $$\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu)}{\sigma s_Z}$$

I've been stuck trying to figure out the best way to tackle this problem.  I recognize that it is most likely $t_{n-1}$ because of the fact that $$\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$$ is by a famous theorem.  However, I am unable to get the denominator in that form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed $t_{n-1}$.  Not only is the distribution of $\sigma s_Z$ the same as that of $s_X$, but (here's the substantial point) $s_X$ and $\bar X$ are independent.  Hence the distibution of
$$
\frac{\bar X - \mu}{s_X/\sqrt n}
$$
(which, as it seems you know, is $t_{n-1}$) is the distribution of the quotient of a standard normal random variable by a $\chi_{n-1}$-distributed random variable.

The independence of $\bar X$ and $s_X$ under the present assumptions is perhaps best seen by considering this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\  \vdots\\  X_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \bar X \\  \vdots \\ \bar X \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} X_1-\bar X \\  \vdots \\ X_n-\bar X \end{bmatrix}
$$
If **jointly** normally distributed random variables have covariance zero, then they are independent.  So find $\operatorname{cov}(\bar X, X_i-\bar X)$.

Comment: Hmm...nice!  I've been trying to work out the argument as to why $\sigma s_Z = s_X$ but wasn't able to get all of the details.  Do you have any tips as to how to move forward with that?

Comment: It is not true that $\sigma s_Z=s_X$, but it is true that the _distribution of_ $\sigma s_Z$ equals the _distribution of_ $s_X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $Z = \sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/\sigma \sim Norm(0,1)$ and $Q = (n-1)s^2/\sigma^2 \sim Chisq(n - 1).$ Then $Z/\sqrt{Q/(n-1)} \sim T(n-1).$

Comment: @BruceTrumbo : In order to get that conclusion, you need to mention also that $Z$ and $Q$ are independent. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy. Right, I was continuing your discussion, where you stated independence, to try to clarify the algebra in the denominator for Nick R, who seemed confused by it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy where I'm stuck is figuring out why $\sigma s_Z = s_X$ in distribution....it seems to be clear but I can't figure out a solid way to argue that.

Comment: @NickR : The distribution of $X_i-\mu$ is the same as the distribution of $\sigma Z_i$.  And $X_i-\bar X = (X_i-\mu)-(\bar X-\mu)$, so that has the same distribution as $Z_i-\bar Z$.   And the _joint_ distribution of the correlated random variables $X_i-\bar X$ and $X_j-\bar X$ is the same as that of $Z_i-\bar Z$ and $Z_j-\bar Z$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: . . . or maybe this is simpler: The distribution of $(X_1-\mu,\ldots,X_n-\mu)$ is the same as that of $\sigma(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$. ${}\qquad{}$